# What is the standard results from density estimation?

Tags: nonlinear-regression, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation, local-statistics

Below comes from "Ruppert and Wand, Multivariate Locally weighted least squares regression, 1994, p.7 or p.1352 in the Journal"

[image]

This is about using Kernel function.

But I don't know what 'the standard results from density estimation' is.

Comment: You have quoted the standard results: your question is its own answer!